# How to control the Index in a for statement in DXL

Tags: ibm-doors

For some reason the DXL interpreter does not take into account the fact that I am decrementing i at the end of the for loop. I am trying to navigate through the arrObj[] array by changing the value of "i". I have some buttons that increment(for next object) and decrement(for previous object) the value respectively. Doing the same thing with a while loop crashes the application.

Is there any way to control the index or will DXL always remember the previous value and increment it (even if the user changes it's value within the code).

Here's a snippet from my code:

```
for i in 0:(iTotalObj-1) do
{   
    sAuxType    = arrObj[i]."ObjectType"
    sAuxNr      = number(arrObj[i]) " "
    sAuxObjTxt  = arrObj[i]."Object Text"

    print "\nAfter FOR:"i ""

    if sAuxType == "Test-Case" then
    {
        set(testContent,"Index number: (" number(arrObj[i])   ") -> " arrObj[i]."Object Heading" "")
        set(expectedResults, " ")
        fillRow(sTesterName,sCfgSW,sCfgHW,arrObj[i])
        block(dtbox)
    }
    if sAuxType == "Test-Step" then
    {
        set(testContent,"Index number: (" number(arrObj[i])   ") -> " arrObj[i]."Object Text" "")
        set(expectedResults,richTextWithOle(arrObj[i]."ExpectedResult"))
        fillRow(sTesterName,sCfgSW,sCfgHW,arrObj[i])
        block(dtbox)
    }
    if sAuxType == "Test-Case-Description" then
    {
        set(testContent,"Index number: (" number(arrObj[i])   ") -> " arrObj[i]."Object Text" "")
        set(expectedResults, "Please check the description throroughly")
        fillRow(sTesterName,sCfgSW,sCfgHW,arrObj[i])
        block(dtbox)

        arrObj[i].("TestResult " iTR "") = "n/a"
        arrObj[i].("FR " iTR "") = "n/a"
    }
    i--
    print "\nAfter DECREMENT:"i ""
}
```

On the output box I'll get the following:

```
After FOR:0
After DECREMENT:-1
After FOR:1
After DECREMENT:0
After FOR:2
After DECREMENT:1
```

Answer (score 0):

With that type of for loop I believe DOORS is forcing `i` to the next value in the set. You should be able to use this type of loop instead:

```
for(i=0; i<(iTotalObj-1); i++) {
  ...
}
```

This loop will allow you to manipulate `i` inside the loop.